# how to click on action bar menu items in test app that having only apk using robotium

Tags: robotium

I am testing **APK** file. I dont have source code. I need to click on the action bar menu item
I have tried `solo.clickonActionbaritems` option and it did not work. Please help me. Many thanks!

Comment: Did you find answer? I am also facing same problem I want to click on overflow menu on the action bar and click on setings item. solo.clickOnActionBarItem(0x1); worked before but now its not working, I think something has changed i dont know what, appcompat action bar

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to click on Android Menu button:
[Find your keycode here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)

```
solo.sendKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU);
```

Also I highly recommend to use **Hierarchy viewer** in DDMS to find id of required button.

```
View requiredButton = getViewById(id.reqired_button_id);
solo.clickOnView(requiredButton);

    // Method returns view
    protected View getViewById(int id) {
            View view = solo.getView(id);
            assertNotNull("View is null", view);
            assertTrue("View is not shown", view.isShown());
            return view;
        }
```

Also you can use clickOnText.